# On Heroku, ran db:migrate without error, `schema_migrations` populated, but schema not changed

Tags: activerecord, heroku, sinatra, rake, heroku-postgres

I have a Sinatra app that I'm trying to get deployed with Heroku. The app is running, and works correctly (the parts that don't rely on DB connection).

I have a Postgresql DB created for the app, but for some reason when I try to migrate the DB (my initial migration is to create a handful of tables), though there are no errors, the tables are not created. What's weirder is that the `schema_migrations` table is populated with the timestamps of the migrations, as though they were run correctly.

I tried restarting the app, as well as deleting the DB and creating a new one.

Thanks for any help.

See the output below. There should have been 13 migrations ran.

```
dave@macbook:~/Development/personal/sinatra-app$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: sinatra-app-api
 !    To proceed, type "sinatra-app-api" or re-run this command with --confirm sinatra-app-api

> sinatra-app-api
Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN_URL (DATABASE_URL)... done

dave@macbook:~/Development/personal/sinatra-app$ heroku config
=== sinatra-app-api Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://OWNER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/sinatra-app-database
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN_URL: postgres://OWNER:PASSWORD@HOST:5432/sinatra-app-database

dave@macbook:~/Development/personal/sinatra-app$ heroku pg:psql
psql (9.2.4)
sinatra-app-database=> \dt
No relations found.

dave@macbook:~/Development/personal/sinatra-app$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1128
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
{"production"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"sinatra-app-database", "username"=>"OWNER", "password"=>"PASSWORD", "host"=>"HOST", "port"=>5432}}
** Execute db:migrate
dave@macbook:~/Development/personal/sinatra-app$ heroku pg:psql
psql (9.2.4)

sinatra-app-database=> \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |     Owner
--------+-------------------+-------+----------------
 public | schema_migrations | table | OWNER
(1 row)

sinatra-app-database=> select * from schema_migrations ;
    version
----------------
 20131364733212
 20131364737284
 20131364755591
 20131364755887
 20131364756006
 20131364766771
 20131365332699
 20131365332706
 20131365333238
 20131365334088
 20131365334094
 20131376235209
 20131378061826
(13 rows)
```

Also see the relevant parts of my Rakefile here:

```
# encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env rake
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"
require "active_support/inflector"
require "logger"
require "yaml"
require 'csv'
require 'bundler'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'erb'

desc "Used internally by the Rakefile."
task "environment" do
   environment = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
   configuration = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result)
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(configuration[environment])
end

namespace :db do
   desc "Run database migrations."
   task :migrate => :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil )
   end

   desc "Rollback last <STEPS> migrations. Defaults to 1"
   task :rollback => :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.rollback('db/migrate', ENV["STEPS"] ? ENV["STEPS"].to_i : 1)
   end

    desc "Forwards next <STEPS> migrations. Defaults to 1"
    task :forward => :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.forward('db/migrate', ENV["STEPS"] ? ENV["STEPS"].to_i : 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: Yes, no problems locally

Comment: I wrap each migration in warnings (as I had something similar happen a while back) to confirm the files are actually being run and not just the migrator, e.g. `warn "Running migration, up, 001"` and `warn "001 done!"`.